# "Color for Value" is not working as expected

Tags: matplotlib

If I run the following:

```
print(cm.jet(0))
print(cm.jet(0.25))
print(cm.jet(0.5))
print(cm.jet(0.75))
print(cm.jet(0.99))
print(cm.jet(1))
```

I get:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.503921568627451, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.4901960784313725, 1.0, 0.4775458570524984, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.5816993464052289, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.535650623885918, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.517825311942959, 1.0)
```

So I'm getting the same color for 0 and 1. Am I doing something wrong? I'm using Version 2.1.2 of matplotlib and version 3.5 of python.

**UPDATE**

Ok, it has something to do with int and float.

So:

```
print(cm.jet(0))
print(cm.jet(0.25))
print(cm.jet(0.5))
print(cm.jet(0.75))
print(cm.jet(0.99))
print(cm.jet(1.0))
print(cm.jet(1))
```

gives:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.503921568627451, 1.0, 1.0)
(0.4901960784313725, 1.0, 0.4775458570524984, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.5816993464052289, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.535650623885918, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.517825311942959, 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed confusing. There are two ways to get colors from a [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

- Calling it with a ('n array of) float value(s) between `0.` and `1.`. Here `0.` is the first color of the map, `1.` is the last.
- Calling it with an index, i.e a ('n array of) integer value(s) between `0` and `n-1`, where `n` would be the number of colors in the colormap. Many colormaps have 256 colors, but you can check the `N` attribute, e.g. `print(cm.jet.N)` prints `256`.

This means that you get the same colors via

```
from matplotlib import cm

cm.jet(0.0) == cm.jet(0)
cm.jet(1.0) == cm.jet(255)

cm.jet([0.0, 0.5, 1.0]) == cm.jet([0, 128, 255])
```

In cases of "continuous" colormap, like `jet` or the default `viridis`, you'd usually make sure to use floats and not bother about indices at all.

In cases of a "discrete" colormap, like `tab10` indexing becomes interesting. E.g. the `tab10` colormap contains only 10 colors. To get the third color of that colormap, calling

```
cm.tab10(2)
```

is much easier than dividing by the number of colors to get the corresponding float value.

Suggested reading:

- [Colormaps reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/color/colormap_reference.html)
- [Colormaps tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)